# Use row data and insert it into another table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on travel agency sales report project which preview issued Tickets to employee so he will use and select row that he will close and inter the sale amount

tickets are in table called airfiles and closed tickets will be inserted to table called tickets so there is no need to enter all ticket fields while wh can use or bring ticket data from airfiles table automaticaly and employee will enter only sale amount

my problem is when iam tring to to load selected airfile in ticket create.blade.php it returns with error

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIAjZ.png)

```
class TicketController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $airfiles = Airfile::all();
        $tickets = Ticket::query()
            ->where('pax_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->orWhere('tkt_no', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('dashboard.tickets.index', compact('tickets','airfiles'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $airlines = Airline::all();
        $airfiles = Airfile::all();
        return view('dashboard.tickets.create', array('users' => $users,
            'airlines' => $airlines ,'airfiles' => $airfiles));
    }
}
```

and here is the section in create blade file

```
    <div class="box box-primary">

        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">@lang('site.add')</h3>
        </div><!-- end of box header -->

        <div class="box-body">

            @include('partials._errors')

                <form action="{{ route('dashboard.tickets.store', $airfile->id) }}" method="post">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('post') }}

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.son')</label>
                        @if(Auth::user()->shortsign == '--')
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="son">
                                @foreach ($users as $user)
                                    <option value="{{ $user->shortsign }}">{{ $user->shortsign }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        @else
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="son" disabled>
                                <option value="{{ Auth::user()->shortsign }}">{{ Auth::user()->shortsign }}</option>
                            </select>
                        @endif

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label>@lang('site.pax_name')</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pax_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $airfile->pass }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label>@lang('site.client')</label>
                        <input type="text" name="client" class="form-control" value="{{ old('client') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.mob')</label>
                        <input type="text" name="mob" class="form-control" value="{{ old('mob') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.supplier')</label>
                        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="supplier">
                            <option selected="selected" value="bsp">BSP</option>
                            <option value="online">Online</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.date')</label>

                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="date" name="date"
                                   value="{{ old('date') }}">
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.input group -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.num')</label>
                        <input id="num" class="form-control" placeholder="@lang('site.like') : 2576560361"
                               onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="num"
                               value="{{ old('num') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.rloc')</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rloc" class="form-control" value="{{ old('rloc') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.airline')</label>
                        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="airline">
                            @foreach ($airlines as $airline)
                                <option value="{{ $airline->code }}">{{ $airline->code }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>@lang('site.sector')</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sector" class="form-control" value="{{ old('sector') }}"
                               placeholder="@lang('site.like') : HAS/JED JED/MAA">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>@lang('site.action_type')</label>
                        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="action_type">
                            <option selected="selected" value="issue">@lang('site.issue')</option>
                            <option value="reissue">@lang('site.reissue')</option>
                            <option value="emd">@lang('site.emd')</option>
                            <option value="refund">@lang('site.refund')</option>
                            <option value="void_charge">@lang('site.void_charge')</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>@lang('site.trans_type')</label>
                        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="trans_type">
                            <option selected="selected" value="domestic">@lang('site.domestic')</option>
                            <option value="international">@lang('site.international')</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>@lang('site.payment_type')</label>
                        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="payment_type">
                            <option selected="selected" value="cash">@lang('site.cash')</option>
                            <option value="credit">@lang('site.credit')</option>
                            <option value="advance">@lang('site.advance')</option>
                            <option value="pending">@lang('site.pending')</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.fare')</label>
                        <input id="fare" class="form-control" placeholder="0" onkeyup="main ()" type="text"
                               name="fare" value="{{ old('fare') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.tax')</label>
                        <input id="tax" class="form-control" placeholder="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                               onkeyup="return sum(event)" type="text" name="tax" value="{{ old('tax') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.k7')</label>
                        <input id="k7" class="form-control" placeholder="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                               onkeyup="return sum(event)" type="text" name="k7" value="{{ old('k7') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>@lang('site.profit')</label>
                        <input id="comm" class="form-control" placeholder="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                               onkeyup="return sum(event)" type="text" name="profit" value="{{ old('profit') }}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 text-center text-primary">
                        <label>@lang('site.total_vat')</label>
                        <h4>
                            <label class="total-price " id="total_vat">0</label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 text-center text-danger">
                        <label>@lang('site.total_cost')</label>
                        <h4>
                            <label class="total-price " id="total_cost">0</label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>@lang('site.amount_arabic')</label>
                        <input type="text" id="amount_arabic" name="amount_arabic" class="form-control"
                               value="{{ old('amount_arabic') }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>@lang('site.amount_english')</label>
                        <input type="text" name="amount_english" class="form-control"
                               value="{{ old('amount_english') }}">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 text-center text-danger">
                        <label>@lang('site.total')</label>
                        <h4>
                            <label class="total-price " id="total">0</label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> @lang('site.add')
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </form><!-- end of form -->


        </div><!-- end of box body -->

    </div><!-- end of box -->

</section><!-- end of content -->
```

and this is the route code

```
 //ticket routes
        Route::resource('tickets', 'TicketController')->except(['show']);
```

steps like that
first user will click on use button
[Use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82mge.png)

then ticket details must be loaded automatic to fill its fields
[Ticket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhBcd.png)

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you send **airfiles** to view and in blade use *airfile*

change airfile to airfiles in blade and view .

laravel can't defined airfile variable .

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data as in create view with index `airfiles` and try to access it using `airfile`. This is wrong. You get data in view by using same index name as you pass. So change `airfile` to `airfiles` in create blade.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see this error because it's not defined anywhere in your controller.
in your controller you have this **$airfiles** but not $airfile an you are directly trying to access that.

you will have to run a foreach loop on **$airfiles as $airfile** then extract the column value.

Hope it helps

Comment: Problem when using foreach it bring data from first row but i need selected row